# Definition of the Fourier dimension of a set and sets with zero Fourier dimension

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

Mattila defines in *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension* the Fourier dimension of a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to be

> $\mathrm{dim_F}A = \sup\{s\leq n: \exists \mu \in \mathcal{M}(A):|\hat{\mu}(x)| \leq |x|^{-s/2}\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$

where $\mathcal{M}(A) = \{\mu: \text{$\mu$ is a Borel measure on $A$}, 0 < \mu(A) < \infty, \mathrm{spt}(\mu) \subset A\}$ where $\mathrm{spt}(\mu)$ is the support of $\mu$. To my knowledge Mattila doesn't mention is explicitly, but $s$ is assumed to be on the interval $(0, n]$.

My question is that knowing that there exists sets $A$ with zero Fourier dimension, how do we know that there exists such a measure $\mu$ that $|\hat{\mu}(x)| \leq 1$? Is it just as simple as taking a normlized $\mu$ with $\mu(A) = 1$ (and in particular $\int_{\mathrm{spt}(\mu)}d\mu = 1$) and then bounding

$$|\hat{\mu}(x)| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x}d\mu(\xi)| = |\int_{\mathrm{spt}(\mu)}e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x}d\mu(\xi)| \leq \int_{\mathrm{spt}(\mu)}|e^{2\pi i \xi \cdot x}|d\mu(\xi) = 1$$

Comment: Of course not. That bound is trivial. You have to prove that for all $\mu$ supported on your set, the Fourier transform $\widehat{\mu}(x)$ does not decay polynomially at $x\to \infty$. Think of the Dirac delta, whose Fourier transform is $1$, which does not decay at all.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro This might sound like a trivial question, but are you saying that if we've shown that for no $\mu$ supported in our set does the Fourier transform of $\mu$ tend polynomially to zero, then the Fourier dimension of the said set is zero?

I am just confused by the following: If we know that no $s\in(0,1)$ works, why would this then mean that for $s=0$ we have a suitable measure?

Or is it a combination of what I had written to my post and this comment: $s=0$ works trivially by taking such a normalized $\mu$ and proving that no such $\mu$ exists for $0<s<1$ finishes the proof?

Comment: "are you saying that if we've shown that for no μ supported in our set does the Fourier transform of μ tend polynomially to zero, then the Fourier dimension of the said set is zero?" Exactly. I do not understand the rest of your comment

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In rest of my comment I was trying to ask/think why the Fourier dimension of zero is meaningful, namely how do we know that there exists measures $\mu$ with suitable support s.t. $|\hat{\mu}(x)|\leq 1$?

You might have already answered this in your first comment, but I did not understand how: "*Of course not. That bound is trivial.*" answered my verbatim question of: "*My question is that knowing that there exists sets $A$ with zero Fourier dimension, how do we know that there exists such a measure μ that $|\hat{\mu}(x)|≤1$? *".

Comment: My point is that ALL measures satisfy that bound. You can redo that last computation of this question with whatever measure and still get the bound. That's why it is often called "the trivial bound".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, this clarified a lot!